# Microsoft.AspNetCore DoS vulnerability, how to resolve for .Net Framework projects

Tags: asp.net

I have a .Net Web API project targeting .Net Framework 4.6, in this project I have Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0.0 DLL.

I have read that Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0.0 DLL has DoS (Denial of Service) security vulnerability.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6488

When I look into the recommended resolution it says to upgrade to Version 2.7, now issue is I can't upgrade to 2.7 as highest I can upgraded for .Net Framework is 2.2.0.0 which I already have.

**Query:**

1. Is this security vulnerability only for apps created by targeting
   .Net Core and not .Net Framework even though Microsoft.AspNetCore
   2.2.0.0 library is used?
2. If first is true, then does it mean I don't have to do anything for this security vulnerability? If not, then what should I do to get over this security concern (given that I can't upgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore to 2.7 in a .Net Framework project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All our security advisories include sections describing how to detect if you're affected and how to update. The linked issue has this down in the "Advisory FAQs". In this case you need to install the latest version of the Windows Hosting Bundle. This is true **even if you are using .NET Framework**. That particular vulnerability is in the ASP.NET Core Module for IIS, which is the native component that allows you to host ASP.NET Core apps (on both .NET Core and .NET Framework) in IIS. If you install the hosting bundle, all your ASP.NET Core apps (including those targeting .NET Framework) should be protected from this issue. The FAQs also include instructions on how to verify you have the right version installed (using a PowerShell script to check the version number of the `aspnetcore.dll` file)

For packages: We don't update every single package for every patch release. Only the affected packages are updated. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package hasn't been patched at all, so it's still at `2.2.0`. Other packages, like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages` have had some patches, so they're at versions like `2.2.5`. You should always ensure that all your packages that start with `Microsoft.AspNetCore` have the latest patch version (the third component of the version number) installed in order to get all necessary security updates.