# What is the update/patch policy on vulnerable Microsoft.AspNetCore package versions?

Tags: asp.net-core, security, nuget-package, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have some quite old library code using *Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0*, which has vulnerability [CVE-2019-0548](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-0548). The library is compiled for targets Netstandard 2.0 and NET 6.0, consumed by NET Framework 4.7.2+ and .NET 6.0. NET Framework is only supported for downward compatibility.

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58560546/832306).

The docs at Mend (formerly Whitesource) recommend to update the package to version 2.1.7. Since I had 2.2.0, I expected it to be newer.

But in fact, *Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.7* is from 2019, newer than 2.2.0 from 2018. I know with .NET Core 2.2, a shared framework was introduced (similar to the old .NET Framework?). The vulnerability is also somewhere in native IIS code and to be fixed by runtime updates.

**But why is version 2.1.x patched and 2.2.x not? Should I downgrade to 2.1.7 for Netstandard 2.0?**

*Note: I got rid of the vulnerability warning by conditional `<PackageReference ... />`, only for .NET Standard 2.0. For .NET 6.0, the package isn't referenced, but a `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />` exists, which, if I understand correctly, limits execution to runtime version at least 2.2.8, no lower.
It was also possible to completely omit some of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.Extensions` 2.x packages for NET 6.0.*

#### Edit:

I think *FrameworkReference* supports no *Version* attribute for minimum runtime version; i confused this with *PackageReference* examples.

The vulnerability also appeared again in Mend, probably due to irregular behavior in scans.

Comment: It's end of life for 2.x... you should bite the bullet and move to .net6. In the meantime, there are update links for 2.1 AND 2.2 here: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2019-0548  I think the recommendation for 2.1.7 must be for people who wanted to patch 2.1... since you are on 2.2, you'd patch 2.2.

Comment: The "netstandard2.0" target includes older .NET and core... starting at core 3.x, everything was in core, so no need for older .NET 4.x run-time.  You'd move to ".netstandard 2.1" for > 2.x methinks... but it'd be irrelevant if you publish self-contained (run-time included).

Comment: We still need netstandard2.0 for .NET Framework downward compatibility; netstandard2.1 doesn't support framework. What I now do, is make all references/versions of AspNetCore 2.2.x packages conditional, for standard/framework only. Meanwhile, the vulnerability appears again; Mend SaaS seems not very reliable, currently (of course, because it's still in standard/framework).

Comment: all/most of the old .NET Framework stuff is in Core, so it won't be all that difficult to migrate.  (The ultimate goal was/is to have one .NET methinks....)  And since you can deploy self-contained you won't need any .net installed on the machine(s) you are running on.